# C# WPF Убрать из RichTextBox перевод строки

Tags: c#, wpf

Как убрать из  RichTextBox отступ в конце строки?

Вот такой стандартный который виден при выделении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто `Trim` использовать не вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал **EvgeniyZ**, очень легко воспользоваться методом `Trim()`

Метод возвращает новую строку, в которой удалены все начальные и конечные вхождения заданного набора знаков из текущего объекта `String`

Например:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      char[] charsToTrim = { '*', ' ', '\''};
      string banner = "*** Much Ado About Nothing ***";
      string result = banner.Trim(charsToTrim);
      Console.WriteLine("Trimmmed\n   {0}\nto\n   '{1}'", banner, result);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Trimmmed
//          *** Much Ado About Nothing ***
//       to
//          'Much Ado About Nothing'
```

В вашем случае будет текст в выделении